# Will my AsyncTask be faster if i move it to a different file?

Tags: android

I just have some really quick question about `AsyncTask`

See this my `AsyncTask` and the class that is it in

```
public class ListView extends ListActivity {    


    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> questionList;        

     final String TAG_RESULTS = "results";
     final String TAG_QUESTION_SUBJECT = "Subject";
     final String TAG_QUESTION_NUMANSWERS = "NumAnswers";
     final String TAG_QUESTION = "question";
     final String TAG_QUESTION_CONTENT = "Content";
     final String TAG_QUESTION_CHOSENANSWER = "ChosenAnswer";
     final String TAG_ANSWERS = "Answers";
     final String TAG_ANSWER = "Answer";    
     final String TAG_ANSWERS_CONTENT = "content";      
     final String TAG_QUERY = "query";
     final String TAG_COUNT = "count";
     ProgressDialog pDialog;
     LoadAllData mTask; 

            JSONArray question = null;          
            android.widget.ListView lv;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        //setContentView(R.layout.listview);        

    questionList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>(); 

    mTask = new LoadAllData();

         mTask.execute();

        }


    @Override   
    protected void onListItemClick(android.widget.ListView l, View v, int pos, long id) {
         super.onListItemClick(l, v, pos, id);  

          HashMap<String, String> item = questionList.get(pos);

          Intent i = new Intent(ListView.this, SingleListItem.class);
          i.putExtra(TAG_QUESTION_SUBJECT, item.get(TAG_QUESTION_SUBJECT));
          i.putExtra(TAG_QUESTION_CONTENT, item.get(TAG_QUESTION_CONTENT));
          i.putExtra(TAG_QUESTION_CHOSENANSWER, item.get(TAG_QUESTION_CHOSENANSWER));
          startActivity(i);

            }     

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {              

        if (mTask != null && mTask.getStatus() != AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED)
        {
            mTask.cancel(true);
        }          
        super.onBackPressed();

    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

     if (mTask != null && mTask.getStatus() != AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED)
     {
        mTask.cancel(true);
      }  

        super.onDestroy();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


     if (pDialog != null)
     {
         if(pDialog.isShowing())
         {
             pDialog.dismiss();
         }
            super.onPause();

      }  

    }

    class LoadAllData extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();             
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ListView.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading Data. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();           
        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {  

            pDialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener(){ 
                public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) { 
                    mTask.cancel(true); 
                    finish(); 
            } 
       }); 

            try {
                Intent in = getIntent();
                String searchTerm = in.getStringExtra("TAG_SEARCH");
                String query = URLEncoder.encode(searchTerm, "utf-8");
                String URL = "http://example.com";
                JSONParsser jParser = new JSONParsser();
                JSONObject json = jParser.readJSONFeed(URL);
                try {

                    JSONArray questions = json.getJSONObject("all").getJSONArray("questions");

                    for(int i = 0; i < questions.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject question = questions.getJSONObject(i);


                    String Subject = question.getString(TAG_QUESTION_SUBJECT);
                    String ChosenAnswer = question.getString(TAG_QUESTION_CHOSENANSWER);
                    String Content = question.getString(TAG_QUESTION_CONTENT);

                           HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                           map.put(TAG_QUESTION_SUBJECT, Subject);
                           map.put(TAG_QUESTION_CONTENT, Content);
                           map.put(TAG_QUESTION_CHOSENANSWER, ChosenAnswer);

                           questionList.add(map);

                }


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

                return null;       

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_URL) {

        if(file_URL!=null && file_URL.equals("0")) {  
            pDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(ListView.this, "No data found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();

        }else{

        if (pDialog != null && pDialog.isShowing()) pDialog.dismiss();
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), questionList,
                    R.layout.listelements,
                    new String[] { TAG_QUESTION_SUBJECT }, new int[] {
                    R.id.Subject,});

            setListAdapter(adapter);                

        }}}
```

Now the question I wanted to ask is if I take my `AsyncTask` out of this current activity and put it in a different file, will it make the execution of my `doInBackGround` method faster.  I am asking this because when my `AsyncTask` is executing, it takes quite some time to finish and also in my logcat this message `09-24 20:12:55.928: I/Choreographer(824): Skipped 195 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.` fills up my whole logcat when the `AsyncTask` is executing.  I just want to know will It make a difference if I move it.

Comment: `The application may be doing too much work on its main thread` Don't do work on your main thread.

Comment: It isn't clear that the problem is in the code you've pasted in.  You might like to include the rest of the code.

Comment: @DavidSainty did you see my updated question?

Answer (score 2):

> I just want to know will It make a difference if I move it.

No, it will not.

Moreover, the behavior of `doInBackground()` is not the source of your difficulty. It is something else, perhaps your `onPostExecute()`. The error is very explicit about your problem ("may be doing too much work on its main thread"), and `doInBackground()` does its work on another thread.

Comment: I have two 'if' statements in my 'onPostExecute' could that be it

Comment: @InmanDouche: I have no idea. Use Traceview to determine where your specific performance issues are.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that this code block belongs to doInbackground method ?

```
pDialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener(){ 
    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) { 
    mTask.cancel(true); 
    finish(); 

});
```

The error clearly points that you are doing extra work not suitable for UI thread (which is not clear in your code above)

Comment: That my listener to cancel the asynctask

Comment: Agreed, this should be done in `onPreExecute()`, not `doInBackground()`. While it is not the source of the slowdown, all work that touches the UI really should be done on the main application thread.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding updated code - it still isn't clear where the problem is.

I suggest you go through the background code and look for anything touching the activity or UI - there might be some obscure problem caused by issuing UI thread requests on the background thread.  setOnCancelListener() is one.  getIntent() is another.  Comment them out and see what happens.

Then start breaking it down.  Comment out bits of code to remove them from the equation and see if it changes anything.

It's going to take a bit of hunting at this point, so the smaller you can make the errant code the better.  Eventually you'll figure out what is causing the problem, and from that you can figure out why.